# The number of solutions of $x^n = e$ in a finite group is a multiple of n, whenever n divides the group order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Prove that in a finite group G the number of solutions of the equation $x^n = e$ is a multiple of n, whenever n divides the order of the group.

I feel there is a very simple answer to this question, but it eludes me.

Comment: @Ivo Terek This is not necessarily true. Take $\mathbb{Z}_2\ast \mathbb{Z}_2$. The two generators are of finite order but their product is not. If the group is finite, then this is the whole group.

Comment: My bad. I've fixed the title now.

Comment: @Ivo Terek Just on the question that was a mistake in the old title, could you explain how Langrange's theorem applied to that set proves the result?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The number of generators of a cyclic group of order $d$ is $\phi(d)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. Thus the number of elements of order $d$ in a group must be a multiple of $\phi(d)$.

What you are looking for is the sum of the numbers of elements of order $d$, where $d \mid n$.