# Number of solutions to $x^n=e$ in group $G$ is divisible by $n$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, finite-groups

**My question is, can we prove that the number of solutions to $x^n=e$ in group $G$ is divisible by $n$, for $n | |G|$**

Apparently the answer is it is indeed true, infact for the equation $x^n = a$ for any $a \in G $ also, however I have had many ideas each of which having a small flaw with them.

For example I attempted induction on order of $G$ as follows:

Assume true for all groups of order $ \leq k$. Consider $|G| = k+1$.

If $G$ is cyclic, we show fairly easily the result holds. (In fact if I recall correctly there are $n$ solutions for each divisor $n$).

If $G$ is not cyclic, we can look at the subgroups of $G$. It'd be nice to say the number of solutions in each group is divisible by $n$ by the induction hypothesis and get the desired answer by inclusion-exlusion for solutions in all the subgroups, however we could potentially have a subgroup of order  less than $n$ and still contain a solution.

So if we were able to show it works for all the subgroups of orders $ < n$ collectively we would be done. I have no idea whether this can work though.

I did see this question [The number of solutions of $x^n = e$ in a finite group is a multiple of n, whenever n divides the group order.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034359/the-number-of-solutions-of-xn-e-in-a-finite-group-is-a-multiple-of-n-whene) however I couldn't find much help on it. From the hint given I managed to show $no. solutions = \sum_{ d|n} \lambda_{i} \phi(d)$ for some $\lambda_{i}$s, however they could be different so I can't just use the well know summing of euler-phi formula.

**Any solution/ideas would be very much appreciated.**

Comment: I think the condition $n$ dividing the order of $G$ is important in your question. Because otherwise it is not true. For instance, the number of solutions to $3x = 0$ in $\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$ is $1$ and that's not divisible by $3$.

Comment: @AlexMacedo Yes true, but I was just including '0 as divisible by every number' although maybe by definition of divisibility that's not correct. Basically I thought it may help have the result for all $n$ in some form of induction but yes fair point.

Comment: 0" is divisible by every nonzero integer but that's not a problem. The issue is $x^n = 1$ will always have at least one solution ($x = 1$) and the order of $x$ must divide $n$. If $n$ and $G$ are coprime, then the order of $x$ must be one in which case the number of solutions to $x^n = 1$ is $1$ but $1$ is not divisible by $n$ if $n > 1$.

Comment: @AlexMacedo ah yes sorry for being stupid, will edit in question

Comment: For starters, this holds at least when $n$ is a prime dividing the order of $G$. It is a neat exercise in Martin Isaacs book (probably also elsewhere) *Finite Group Theory* (AMS Graduate Studies in Mathematics, #92). Past midnight here, so I'm not gonna spoil the fun...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I will look at this, thanks. Do you know if this can be extended for the general case?

Comment: You are considering induction on $k=|G|$. Also $n$ is divisor of  $|G|$. So when you pass from $k$ to $k+1$, then $n$ will not divide $k+1$, so this type of induction will not work. Certainly there is inductive proof, but actually we need induction on $|G|$ as well as $n$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is *precisely* the Theorem of Frobenius.

Without representation theory, there is a proof, by induction; but more - it is double induction (on order of group and also on $n$). I didn't feel the proof elementary, so I am not writing proof here. But you may see following.

This theorem appears in *very few* standard books of Group Theory (Zassenhaus, M. Hall, Huppert, and no other books I saw giving group-theoretic proof).

However, a group-theoretic proof has been appeared in an interesting article in American Mathematical Monthly: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/3004416017467.pdf.bannered.pdf

The interesting things about this article is that it involves some niceapplications of it, and also gives *all* the sources of earlier known proofs.

Hope this would help! Let me know!